# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError Jackson databind and Spark

Tags: json, scala, jackson, apache-spark

I am trying to run spark-submit with Spark 1.1.0 and Jackson 2.4.4. I have scala code which uses Jackson to de-serialize JSON into case classes. That works just fine on its own, but when I use it with spark I get the following error:

```
15/05/01 17:50:11 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.addField(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/AnnotatedField;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyName;ZZZ)V
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaPropertiesCollector.com$fasterxml$jackson$module$scala$introspect$ScalaPropertiesCollector$$_addField(ScalaPropertiesCollector.scala:109)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaPropertiesCollector$$anonfun$_addFields$2$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(ScalaPropertiesCollector.scala:100)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaPropertiesCollector$$anonfun$_addFields$2$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(ScalaPropertiesCollector.scala:99)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaPropertiesCollector$$anonfun$_addFields$2.apply(ScalaPropertiesCollector.scala:99)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaPropertiesCollector$$anonfun$_addFields$2.apply(ScalaPropertiesCollector.scala:93)
    at scala.collection.GenTraversableViewLike$Filtered$$anonfun$foreach$4.apply(GenTraversableViewLike.scala:109)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.SeqLike$$anon$2.foreach(SeqLike.scala:635)
    at scala.collection.GenTraversableViewLike$Filtered$class.foreach(GenTraversableViewLike.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$$anon$5.foreach(SeqViewLike.scala:80)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaPropertiesCollector._addFields(ScalaPropertiesCollector.scala:93)
```

Here is my build.sbt:

```
//scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.4"
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.10.5"

retrieveManaged := true

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.1.1" % "test",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "0.20.2",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "0.94.6"
)

//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.1.0"


libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.4.4"
//libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.3.1"
//libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.5.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1"

resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
```

As you can see, I have tried many different versions of Jackson.

Here is the shell script I use to run spark submit:

```
#!/bin/bash
sbt package

CLASS=com.org.test.spark.test.SparkTest

SPARKDIR=/Users/user/Desktop/
#SPARKVERSION=1.3.0
SPARKVERSION=1.1.0
SPARK="$SPARKDIR/spark-$SPARKVERSION/bin/spark-submit"

jar_jackson=/Users/user/scala_projects/lib_managed/bundles/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala_2.10/jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.4.4.jar

"$SPARK" \
  --class "$CLASS" \
  --jars $jar_jackson \
  --master local[4] \
  /Users/user/scala_projects/target/scala-2.10/spark_project_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
  print /Users/user/test.json
```

I use `--jars` to the path of the jackson jar to the spark-submit command. I have even tried different versions of Spark. I have also even specified the paths for the Jackson jars databind, annotations, etc but that didn't resolve the issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Looks like you have version conflicts

Comment: Even if I specify all the paths to the 2.4.4 Jackson jars, it still does not work. I believe spark even already comes with its own Jackson 2.4.4 libraries except for scala module which is why I only currently pass that to --jars

Comment: @Jens can you elaborate with which? and how I can resolve those?

Comment: `Jackson-databind` and `jackson-module-scala`

Comment: Please refer to my answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806356/spark-running-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-codehaus-jackson-annotat/30179627#30179627

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem where my play-json jar was using jackson 2.3.2 and spark was using jackson 2.4.4.
While I was running the spark application, it was unable to find the method in jackson-2.3.2 and I got the same exception.

I checked the maven dependency hierarchy for jackson. It displayed the version it took and which jar (Here play used 2.3.2) and as my play-json placed at first in dependency list, it took 2.3.2 version.

So I tried placing the play dependency at the end of the all dependencies/after the spark dependency and it worked pretty well. It took 2.4.4 this time and version 2.3.2 is omitted.

[Source](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html):

> Note that if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree, until Maven 2.0.8 it was not defined which one would
>   win, but since Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that
>   counts: the first declaration wins.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem with jackson and spark. As I was using SBT, like user1077071, I followed the following steps:

1. Installed the excellent dependency Plugin for SBT:
   https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph
2. Discovered that in my case, play-json was depending on jackson 2.3
3. added jackson 2.4. to my libraryDependencies

I did have to aplly that approach to mulatiple jackson libs though: core, annotations and databind. databind was the culprit, but the otehrs should be bumped as well to avoid clashes.

After that, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason I think is the you don't specify the right dependency.

If you use 3-rd party library and then `submit to Spark` directly, the better way is to use `sbt-assembly` (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly).

Comment: thank you for your comment. I have tried using sbt assembly but I still run into the same exception

Answer (score 0):

got java.lang.NoSuchMethodError Jackson databind for method `...introspect.AnnotatedMember.annotations()`
Issue resolved by updating maven dependency for **jackson-databind** version **2.9.0.pr3** - to **2.9.1**

Answer (score 0):

I had

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonStreamContext.<init>(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonStreamContext;)V
```

error when updated com.fasterxml.jackson.core libraries from 2.8.9 to 2.9.1

in my case, resolution is to look through gradle dependencies and in build.gradle exclude all conflicts:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.7.RELEASE') {
    exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"
}

compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:1.5.7.RELEASE') {
    exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"
}

compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.1') {
    exclude module: "jackson-annotations"
    exclude module: "jackson-core"
}

compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.1')

compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.1')

compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.3'

compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.12:2.9.1') {
    exclude group: "org.scala-lang"
    exclude module: "jackson-core"
    exclude module: "jackson-annotations"
    exclude module: "jackson-databind"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest spark version `3.0.0-preview2`, the below configuration is a working `build.sbt`:

```
name := "scala-streams"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"
val sparkVersion = "3.0.0-preview2"
val playVersion="2.8.1"

val jacksonVersion="2.10.1"

//override if you wish to
//dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % jacksonVersion
//dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % jacksonVersion

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % playVersion
)
```