# Submit job to spark with conflicting jackson dependencies?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, jackson

I have an uber-jar created that uses jackson 2.7.5. I'm using spark 1.6.2 (since I am on scala-2.10). However, whenever I try and submit my spark job I get errors about no method found on Feature switches that are in the later jackson version.

I would have assumed that an uber-jar would allow me to bundle my own dependencies even if they conflict with what spark needs to run using some sort of delegating classloader to isolate conflicts.  Is this not the case? If it's not, how do I go about resolving this?

I know there is this answer [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError Jackson databind and Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000607/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-jackson-databind-and-spark) which basically suggests to use the sparks jackson instead of your own, but spark's jackson is quite old now and I have code that relies on the features of the new jackson

Comment: will my jars take precedence over sparks classpath? 8; not then this won't make a difference right? It's clearly picking up jackson from its own classpath and not by first letting me load my own version

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue with multiple netty versions being referenced via the job & the job-server. Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: I ended up pulling the spark source code and updating their depenendencies and creating a custom build

Answer (score 1):

You need to shade the dependency so both versions can coexist. Your newer version path names will be changed to solve the conflict.

In case you are using Maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <groupId><!-- YOUR_GROUP_ID --></groupId>
  <artifactId><!-- YOUR_ARTIFACT_ID --></artifactId>
  <version><!-- YOUR_PACKAGE_VERSION --></version>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version><!-- YOUR_SPARK_VERSION --></version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- YOUR_DEPENDENCIES -->
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion><!-- YOUR_SCALA_VERSION --></scalaVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass><!-- YOUR_APPLICATION_MAIN_CLASS --></mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/maven/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
              <relocations>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>com</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>repackaged.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                  <includes>
                    <include>com.google.common.**</include>
                  </includes>
                </relocation>
              </relocations>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Source: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/manage-spark-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

If using  `--conf` `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` is a possiblity.

Please see my response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57329060/exclusion-of-dependency-of-spark-core-in-cdh/57637349#57637349).