# Exclusion of dependency of spark-core in CDH

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-kafka, hbase, cloudera-cdh

I'm using Structured Spark Streaming to write to HBase data coming from Kafka.

My cluster distribution is : Hadoop 3.0.0-cdh6.2.0, and i'm using Spark 2.4.0

My code is like below :

```
val df = spark
 .readStream
 .format("kafka")
 .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
 .option("subscribe", topic)
 .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
 .load()
 .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)" , "CAST(value AS STRING)")
 .as(Encoders.STRING)

df.writeStream
  .foreachBatch { (batchDF: Dataset[Row], batchId: Long) =>
     batchDF.write
           .options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog->catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "6"))
          .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase").save()
     }
     .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointDirectory)
     .start()
     .awaitTermination()
```

The HBaseTableCatalog use json4s-jackson_2.11 library. This library is included in Spark Core, but with a bad version, which creates conflicts...

To remedy to this problem, I do an exclusion of the json4s-jackson_2.11 library in the spark core, and I add a downgraded version in the pom :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0-cdh6.2.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
      <artifactId>json4s-jackson_2.11</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
  <artifactId>json4s-jackson_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

When I execute the code in my locale machine, it works perfectly, but the problem, is when I submit it in the cloudera cluster, I have the first error of the conflict of librairies :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse(Lorg/json4s/JsonInput;Z)Lorg/json4s/JsonAST$JValue;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableCatalog$.apply(HBaseTableCatalog.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseRelation.<init>(HBaseRelation.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.DefaultSource.createRelation(HBaseRelation.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
        at com.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:129)
        at com.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:126)
```

I know that the cluster have its own libraries of hadoop and spark and that it use them, so, in the spark submit, i make the confs spark.driver.userClassPathFirst and spark.executor.userClassPathFirst at true, but I have another error and I don't understand it :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnSparkHadoopUtil$.<init>(YarnSparkHadoopUtil.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnSparkHadoopUtil$.<clinit>(YarnSparkHadoopUtil.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$1.apply$mcJ$sp(Client.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$1.apply(Client.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$1.apply(Client.scala:83)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.<init>(Client.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1603)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:851)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.PriorityPBImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.Priority
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.Priority.newInstance(Priority.java:39)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.Priority.<clinit>(Priority.java:34)
        ... 15 more
```

Finally, what I want, is to make Spark using the json4s-jackson_2.11 in my pom and not the one in the Spark core

Comment: It looks like the versions of `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.PriorityPBImpl` and `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.Priority` may be different. Perhaps your package contains one of this class or lib? Check the versions of `hadoop-yarn-api` and `hadoop-yarn-common`

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, do not use `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst` and `spark.executor.userClassPathFirst` but intstead, use `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath`.

Definition from the official [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/configuration.html) : "Extra classpath entries to prepend to the classpath of the driver."

- "prepend", as in, put in front of Spark’s core classpath.

Example :

> --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=C:\Users\Khalid\Documents\Projects\libs\jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Khalid\Documents\Projects\libs\jackson-core-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Khalid\Documents\Projects\libs\jackson-databind-2.6.0.jar

This solved my problem (conflict between the version of Jackson i want to use, and the one spark is using).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did as you suggest but then it seemed it wasn't using the jars I prepended to the class path. Any other suggestions?